# Open Instagram photo page in new window and scroll down page / focus on new comment field

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

Is there any way to open an instagram photo url in a new window and then open the Comments section and focus on the new comment field? If it's not possible to focus on the new comment field, how about at least scrolling down the page to the bottom of the page?

I have no problem opening the new window.

I tried scrollTo function on the new window but that doesn't do anything. I also tried to add #reactModalMountPoint to the end of the URL, which works when the page is already loaded, but if you try to do that for the new window via js is get truncated to just the instagram url. I think that is some sort of security feature instagram photo pages have.

An example of a photo page is: http://instagram.com/p/bZelqhxirx

Answer (score 1):

Either way, someone is going to have to run some code on that page to find and highlight the comment.

Unfortunately, unless instagram has that implemented with php GET's, or has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the header of that page, it should be impossible.

If they do have Access-Control open, you can ajax in the page then use Jquery to find and highlight the comment, the push the url state to the proper page.  This is really, really unlikely because you could also set the login submit button to post wherever you want.

http://css.dzone.com/articles/ajax-requests-other-domains

Comment: I don't think Access-Control is open because I wasn't even able to iframe those photo pages.

Comment: That makes sense.  Having the power to change anything about the way a user see's an outside webpage could be pretty harmful.  Your best bet, if you really want to go for it, is make a plugin for browsers that does it.  If you make it work for multiple sites, I'm sure someone else out there could use a comment navigator.

Comment: hmm... hadn't thought about that. May not be a bad idea. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, if you like my answer, could you please mark it?  I currently can't ask questions and am trying to work up the reputation to be able to again.